# How to ignore None values when I map over a collection

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
for {
  totalUsers = currentUsers.map { u =>
    newUsersMap.get(u.username.get).map { t =>
      FullUser(t.username, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.batch, t.description)
    }
  }
} yield {
  totalUsers
}
```

This is returning a `Seq[Option[FullUser]]` when what I want is a `Seq[FullUser]` - i.e. if that call to `u.username.get` returns None, then just ignore it. How do I do this?

Comment: By the way, mixing for comprehension and complex transforms by map is kinda antipattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider flatmapping.

```
val totalUsers = currentUsers.flatMap { u =>
  newUsersMap.get(u.username.get).map { t =>
    FullUser(t.username, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.batch, t.description)
  }
}
```

For some explanation how `Seq`, `Option`, and `flatMap` work together, see for example [this blog post](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/collection-scala-flatmap-examples-map-flatten).

Comment: If `u.username` is an `Option` that might be `None`, I would suggest `u.username.flatmap(newUsersMap.get).map { t => ... `

Comment: @Kigyo how is this different?

Comment: @cm22 If `u.username` is an `Option` and has no value (aka `None`), calling `u.username.get` will throw an exception. My suggestion also considers this case.

Answer (score 5):

Just try for comprehension

```
for {
  user <- currentUsers
  username <- user.username.toList      //you need to convert to seq type to prevent ambiguous option seq mix problems.
  t <- newUserMap.get(username).toList
} yield FullUser(t.username, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.batch, t.description)
```

for mix with `flatMap` or `map` is not readable.